# Build Standalone Release Porject CryEngine V

Tags: c++, build, export, project, cryengine

I'm making my project with CryEngine V (5.5) and I'd like to obtain a release-standalone build. 
I'm really going crazy with that. My porject is the First Person Shooter template with some dependecies on boost and OpenSSL.
I'm able to build the release and profile solution and if I build the "Packaged Build" the stand alone executables under the bin folder run with no problem on my machine. My problem is when I try to export the built package on another machine: The game says that it can't find the Game.dll. On the documentation I can't find some reliable references or a clean example (if I try to follow any on the required steps I got errors everywhere).
Can anybody explain me how to do it properly? The documentation is TOO poor for a clear comprehension about this process.

Thanks

Comment: So you do copy the dll, too. Don't you? Where to on the target machine? Somewhere covered by the PATH variable?

Comment: Yes I tried to copy all kind of dlls sveveral time. I'm a bit confused about the target machine setting: shouldn't the packed build directly check in the bin folder?

Comment: That is helpful information. I propose to [edit] the question and add it right there.